# Communicating between two devices using hostname on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hostname

I am having two linux devices dev1 and dev2. my dev1 ip is 192.168.1.1, dev2 ip is 192.168.1.2,

```
both are in the   same network.

when ping 192.168.1.1 from dev2 to dev1, i am able to ping.

when i have added /etc/hosts with "192.168.1.1 dev1" on dev1, and tried to ping dev1 from dev2 using 
$pin dev1

I got unknown hostname

when i have added /etc/hosts with "192.168.1.1 dev1" on dev2, and tried to ping dev1 from dev2 using

$pin dev1

it is working,  but this is not what we are expecting. Without any change from dev2, 

we want to ping dev1. 

In between any DNS server should be configured ? Please help us .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

```
when i have added /etc/hosts with "192.168.1.1 dev1" on dev1, and tried to ping dev1 from dev2 using 
$ping dev1

I got unknown hostname
```

You added entry in dev1 machine and trying to ping from Dev2, Dev2 does not have /etc/hosts entry for Dev1

```
 Hence you are getting Unknown hostname
```

Next:

```
when i have added /etc/hosts with "192.168.1.1 dev1" on dev2, and tried to ping dev1 from dev2 using

$ping dev1
```

Yes this work, because you have added your dev1 entry in dev2 /etc/hosts file, now your dev2 machine able to resolve ip address of dev1  from /etc/hosts file.

If you want resolve IP address without adding entries in /ect/hosts file, then you need to set up dns server, make dev1 and dev2 as dns clients, then you can able to ping with hosts names

Without DNS setup, you have to add  /etc/hosts entries in both  dev1 and dev2  Machines like below

Example in Dev1 machine add below entries in /etc/hosts file:

```
  192.168.1.1 dev1 # Dev1 IP address
  192.168.1.2 dev2 # Dev2 IP address
```

Example in Dev2 machine add below entries in /etc/hosts file:

```
  192.168.1.1 dev1 # Dev1 IP address
  192.168.1.2 dev2 # Dev2 IP address
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thank you for the response. If you want resolve IP address without adding entries in /ect/hosts file, then you need to set up dns server, make dev1 and dev2 as dns clients, then you can able to ping with hosts names. Where i can create dns server dev1 or dev2.

Comment: You have setup a DNS server separate machine, but you can implement DNS in existing machine dev1 or dev2 too. You can setup by using windows or Linux host.   For Linux follow this link https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/install-dns-server/

Comment: Hi Sagar, One clarification my device ip will always change. In that case is it better to create seperate DNS server and update dev1 ip and dev2 ip there or i will create DNS server in dev1 where ip is always changing and update this DNS server in dev2 to access dev1 with hostname

Comment: If your device IP is changing because your device might configured with DHCP, you should configure with static IP

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thanks for replying. Currently our device is having dynamic ip. We want to update the host name and ip whenever new ip is getting assigned. Can we use ddclient and achieve the same.

Comment: Create another post for IP assignment linux,  different linux favors has different network configuration files

Comment: Hi Sagar, I have create new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611877/updating-dynamic-ip-in-local-dns-server-for-hostname-resolution