# Updating Dynamic IP in local DNS server for hostname Resolution

Tags: linux, dns

I am using a devices dev1(hostname:dev1.example.com), dev2 connected in same network through router,

which has connection from ISP.

```
 When device dev1 got dynamic IP assigned, automatically device hostname and IP should be configured
```

in DNS server, so that dev2 can ping dev1 using hostname.

```
When i googled for the same, came across DDNS option. When i gone through it is asking to purchase domain and login with the domain credentials in router configuration.


I want to use my own domain without purchasing and enable DDNS support, is it possible to achieve this.
```

Comment: More information is needed on what you are trying to do here. Do you have an internal DNS server? Hostnames can be resolved through internal DNS or external (public DNS) servers.

Comment: With in the network, we want devices to communicate using hostname, whether it is static or dynamic IP. We are able to resolve the same using mDNS support.

Answer (score 0):

below is the script which will update ip address in /etc/hosts file

```
#!/bin/sh
# Set the server's hostname
myHostName=$HOSTNAME
# Find and remove the current line with hostname at the end of line in /etc/hosts ($ is for end of line)
sed -i '/'$myHostName'$/ d' /etc/hosts
# Lookup the current IP Address and strip it out of the result
ipaddr=$(/usr/sbin/ip addr show eth0 | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')
#  Add the server's current IP Address and HostName to /etc/hosts
echo "$ipaddr $myHostName" >>/etc/hosts
```

Note: You must change eth0 to desired port name in your case

add this script to run every minute  in crontab, so whenever ip changes it will update automatically

```
    # enter below command
    crontab -e

    # add below entry 
    * * * * *     sh /root/update_dns_entry.sh
```

Note this is just a workaround, right way doing this is setting up your mac address to dhcp ip to provide always same ip, since you are getting ip address from ISP, you do not have a control over it

Comment: changing /etc/hosts shouldn't be  done on our device,  we have resolved this issue using mDNS support.

Comment: Great to hear it is working,  Please Add it to answer , it will help others  to setup